# Are there separate desktop and server versions of CentOS?

Tags: centos

I am transitioning from Ubuntu to CentOS. Whereas Ubuntu has separate desktop and server versions, I see only one version of CentOS. It seems to have a GUI. Is there any stripped down version version of CentOS for CLI-only applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closer. There is a "minimal" version available: ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/centos.org/6.0/isos/x86_64/

Comment: +1 this is what I use on my production systems. Note that minimal really is minimal (which is good IMO). I had to install wget, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this.

I think the best way is to download the default ISO image and deselect all packages to get get a minimal install, or install just the packages that you need. Instructions for this are in the CentOS FAQ at [3. Can I install CentOS 5 with just the first CD?](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS5#head-c79c201900d22f163a445f134fcc6c916eb3cb6e). If you want a lightweight OS with just X window or just an Apache webserver, this method is for you.

As an alternative, CentOS provides a "Minimal" ISO. They are also supposed to provide a "LightWeightServer " ISO, but I haven't heard anything else about this LWS version.

The [CentOS 6 Release Announcement](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2011-July/017645.html) says:

> +++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> Minimal Install CD
>
> We have also created a minimal install CD, that would bring up a base 
>   machine with just enough content to have a usable platform. This CD 
>   image will be released in the next few days.
>
> +++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> The LightWeightServer (LWS) CD
>
> In order to bring back the CentOS-4 Server CD style single iso image,
>   we  are creating a LWS varient of the main distro. Details for this
>   will be  posted in the next few days with release happening after the
>   live media  and the minimal cd editions.

The Minimal ISO is available on CentOS mirrors. Look for CentOS-6.0-x86_64-minimal.iso on the following mirror, for example:

http://linux.mirrors.es.net/centos/6.0/isos/x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

No

But you can select to install GUI or not during installation...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after you install the system all you have to do is to set the initdefault line in /etc/inittab to 3 from 5.  For example:

```
 id:3:initdefault:
```

Comment: This still has the packages on the system which takes up disk space and provides the potential for exploitation.

Comment: I guess it depends on your selection of packages at installation wouldn't it?

Comment: Not really. Runlevel 5, by definition, launches a display manager. The OP wanted to avoid installing a GUI. http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-x-runlevels-5.html